# When I create a test method in Django, what exactly is 'self' referring to?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, self

My understanding of 'self' is that it means something like "an instance of the class which contains this method". Thus, when the default django test reads:

```
class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_basic_addition(self):
```

we are in some sense passing to test_basic_addition an instance of SimpleTest, to which at some point the actions defined in the setUp method (if any) have been applied. Presumably `manage.py test` creates this instance somehow, but I don't really understand what it is! What's really going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the test runner does create an instance of your test class (`SimpleTest`) for each test method that you create. `self` refers to that instance.

From the [`unittest` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase):

> Each instance of `TestCase` will run a single test method: the method named `methodName`.

This means you can use additional 'helper' methods on your test class and call these with `self.name_of_helper_method()`.

You generally don't have to worry about how the `unittest` framework loads and runs your tests, but the [`unittest` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) can explain this in further detail.

Comment: This was a very helpful answer. I found the link to the unittest documentation especially helpful, as I had had trouble finding the relevant documentation (I was looking for Django docs rather than Python ones). Thanks!